# Converting a list of strings into integers

Tags: python

First, I have searched and found some other solutions that seem very plausible and should work, but for whatever reason after trying them with my data - those solutions don't work. I am using python 2.7.6

I am attempting to convert a list of strings into integers so I can add them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
numlist = list()
total = 0
#open the file
f = open('c:/Users/Home/Documents/homework/python_webdata/regex_sum_21441.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    z= re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if z != []:
    numlist.append(z)


print numlist

#attempting to add up the int's from the list (which doesnt work) 
results = [int(i) for i in numlist]

total = sum(results)
```

My data prints out correctly, and looks something like this before I attempt to convert it to ints

```
[['2261'], ['2504', '4529'], ['3698', '2693', '3291'], ['3556', '9753', '4059'], ['113', '8261', '157'], ['8059', '1055'], ['1060'], ['2412', '1860'], ['3589'], ['3319'], ['475'], ['6802',
```

but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Home\Documents\homework\python_webdata\lesson 2 code.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       results = [int(i) for i in numlist] TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: You don't have a list of strings, you have a list *of lists* of strings...

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append`

Comment: Why would this ever be downvoted?

Comment: im courious as to the same (regarding the down vote)

Comment: can you help me understand why this is a "list of list of strings"? Is it because of my code? Did you notice this because of my provided output?

Answer (score 2):

As one of the comments put appropriately, you have list of lists containing integers because of the "append" you use.

Put

```
numlist.extend(z)
```

instead of

```
numlist.append(z)
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the issue here is with the `z= re.findall('[0-9]+', line)` as this will return a list of strings, now, after `numlist.append(z)`, you are appending the whole `z` list into `numlist` and that's why you get a list of list of strings.

Now,

`results = [int(i) for i in numlist]` will not work as you have in your `numlist` lists of strings and `int(i)` cannot convert a list into integers, you still have to flatten it, so, I think your best option is `numlist.extend(z)` to keep `numlist` flat with strings only (not a list of lists).

Another solution is to flatten your `numlist` this way:

`results = [int(item) for lst in numlist for item in lst]`

Note: As improvement to your code and sticking with best practices, it is better to use `with open(file, mode) as f:` as this will make sure that your file is closed without mentioning `f.close()` explicitly, this way:

```
with open('c:/Users/Home/Documents/homework/python_webdata/regex_sum_21441.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        z= re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
        if z != []:
            numlist.extend(z)
```